# Applying Physics on USDZ model in RealityKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, usdz

I'm trying to load Entity from a USDZ file and then apply physics to its `ModelEntity`

I'm using toy_robot_vintage model from Apple's gallery. It contains an animation that I want to use, hence I'm loading the `Entity`. I figured out, I can't add physics to `Entity` because it does not conform to the `HasPhysicsBody`, so I get the `vintage_robot_animRig_model_body` and apply the `PhysicsBodyComponent` on it. However, it's not working. Which `ModelEntity` should I apply physics to and how should applying physics to different `ModelEntity` in hierarchy should reflect on my model?

I also tried to add a custom `Entity` subclass that conforms to the protocol, but after I create an object, I don't see it conforms to it.

This is what I have so far:

```
let modelEntity = robotEntity.findEntity(named: "vintage_robot_animRig_model_body")
let physics = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, material: .default, mode: .dynamic)   
modelEntity?.components.set(physics)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [generateCollisionShapes()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/3244071-generatecollisionshapes) instance method to activate physics and run collisions detection:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    let robot = try! Entity.loadAnchor(named: "robot")
    robot.scale = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03]
    let headEntity = robot.findEntity(named: "vintage_robot_animRig_model_head")
    
    robot.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
    
    let physics = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, 
                                             material: .default, 
                                                 mode: .dynamic)
    headEntity?.components.set(physics)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(robot)
    
    return arView
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, you're doing great things for the community!